# Variable leading zeroes in C99 printf

Tags: c, printf

I'm writing a Multiprecision Library in C99. Depending on which platform my code is compiled I am selecting a different Base of representation.

So, for instance, let's say that on platform X the system select BASE=100; and on platform Y BASE=10000;

Let's say I'm representing big unsigned int as follow:

```c
typedef struct a {
       big_enough_uint *digits;
       unsigned int length;
       unsigned int last;
} bigUint;
```

So when i'm on BASE-100 system I want my print function to be

```
void my_print(bigUint *A){
     unsigned int i=0;

     fprintf(stdout,"%d",A->digits[0]);
     if(i!= A->last){
          for(;i<=A->last;i++)
                fprintf(stdout,"%02d",A->digits[i]);
     }
     printf(stdout,"\n");
}
```

While on BASE-10000 systems I want it to be something like

```c
void my_print(bigUint *A){
     unsigned int i=0;

     fprintf(stdout,"%d",A->digits[0]);
     if(i!= A->last){
          for(;i<=A->last;i++)
                fprintf(stdout,"%04d",A->digits[i]);
     }
     printf(stdout,"\n");
}
```

Why i want to do so??

Let's say i have the following number:

```
12345600026789
```

In BASE-100 representation the digits array will be (little-endian form):

```
12|34|56|0|2|67|89
         ^ ^ I want ONE LEADING ZEROES
```

while in BASE-10000:

```
12|3456|2|6789
        ^ I want THREE LEADING ZEROES
```

Is there a simple way to do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Read about the `*` place holder for the field width in `man printf`.

```
printf("%0*d", 3, 42);
```

gives

```
042
```

and

```
printf("% *s", 42, "alk");
```

gives

```
<39 spaces>alk
```

Comment: What i actually did is defining a macro, something like LOG10_BASE, and using it in printf, as you suggested `printf("%0*d",LOG10_BASE,A->digits[0]);`

Comment: Note that neither the C standard nor POSIX mandates using the space modifier with a string (the behaviour is undefined, strictly); it defines its behaviour with signed and unsigned numbers.  You can also use `printf("%.*d", 3, 42)` to get `042` printed; the Rationale for the C99 standard indicates that the committee prefers this (though the `0` modifier also works).